arcgis pro publishing error --- 00176 Server input path exceeds operating system limit
I am  trying to publish a feature layer using arcgis pro 3.0 to arcgis portal version 11.3.
I have shorten my staging path see screenshot
enter image description here
I have rename my service connection see screenshot
enter image description here
I moved my .sde to closer path(see screenshot)
enter image description here
I renamed my feature layer see screenshot
enter image description here
My db sits on AWS
enter image description here
Still when i publish i get this error.
00176: Server path exceeds operating system limit
Any suggestions would be great
